# Python - How to copy a file from a Windows share to a Linux share

Tags: python, linux, windows, file, copy

I have a system with Windows 7 and want to copy a file from a Windows share to a Linux share. Both shares are mounted after logging in through a logon script (L: and N:).

I want to code a Python program to do this job. I think the best way to do this is

```
shutil.copy("L:/Windows/Path/To/File", "N:/Linux/Path/To/New/Directory/")
```

(because all shares are mounted), but I'm not sure if this could have any side effects and because this is a productive environment, I don't want to risk anything.

Any better ideas or should this work without messing things up?

Thanks!

Comment: Only problem I can see is a race condition

Comment: You mean because the script could be performed befor the shares are mounted? That's not a problem in my case, all shares are mounted after login.
OK, if you do not see other problems than this should be fine. Thanks!